# How do I change the enabling policy of k8S custom scheduler

Tags: kubernetes, kube-scheduler

I have a project to enable `another scheduler`, This requires modifying the enabled policies and weights. After **kubernetes 1.19**, it can be set by `KubeSchedulerConfiguration`， although it is still in the `beta` stage.

My project is **kubernetes 1.18**, how do I view the `default policies` and how do I `override or modify` some policies and weights

I really appreciate any help with this

Comment: I found some information about configuring KubeSchedulerConfiguration on `k8sv1.18`, but I did not find it when I executed `kubectl api-resources`

Comment: V1.18 seems to use only [Policy](https://clouddocs.web.cern.ch/containers/tutorials/scheduling.html#configuring-the-kube-scheduler), I wonder how can I see which policies are used by the `default scheduler`, I only need to change some of them instead of keeping some of them